# Как найти минимальное число, произведение ЦИФР которого равно N?

Tags: c++, python, время, производительность, числа

Дано натуральное число N. Требуется написать программу, которая находит такое минимальное число M (M >= 10), произведение цифр которого равно N.
Примеры: число N - 20, число M - 45. Число N - 1, число M - 11. Если числа M нет, то нужно вывести фразу No solution. Ограничение по времени - 1 секунда.

Пожалуйста, подскажите идею или напишите код на Python или C++ с комментариями.
Код на Python (по алгоритму, который я получил в комментариях):

```
 x = int(input())
 s = []
 if x < 10:
   print(10 * x + 1)
 else:
   for i in range (9, 2, -1):
     if x % i == 0:
        s += [i]
   s.sort(reverse = False)
   for el in s:
     print(el, end = '')
```

Мой изначальный код:

```
x = int(input())
s = []
n = []
if x < 10:
   print(10*1 + x)
else:
   for i in range (1, x + 1):
      if x % i == 0:
         s.append(i)
   for i in range (1, len(s)):
      y = s[i-1] * s[i]
      if y == x:
        print(s[i-1],s[i], sep = '')
        break
```

3 код:

```
x = int(input())
s = []
if x < 10:
    print(10 * x + 1)
else:
    for i in range (9, 2, -1):
        y = x
        while y % i == 0:
            if y % i == 0:
                y = y // i
                s += [y]
    s.sort(reverse = False) 
    print(s)   #проверка, какие числа попали в массив
    for j in range (len(s)-1):
        if s[j] * s[j + 1] == x:
            print(s[j],s[j+1], sep = '')
```

Comment: Есть несколько вопросов: 1) Какое максимальное значение может иметь `N`? 2)Почему во втором примере `M` равно `11`? Ведь `M` может быть и `1`.

Comment: Чему должно быть равно M для N = 11?

Comment: А вообще, перебираете цифры от 9 до 2 в убывающем порядке, делите N на каждую, до тех пор пока делится, и запоминаете цифру, на которую разделили. Потом выводите эти цифры в обратном порядке.

Comment: Yernar, максимальное значение N - 2 * 10 в 6 степени, минимальное - 1. Во втором примере M равно 11, потому что так требует условие задачи (моя вина, в начале не написал более точное условие, сейчас всё отредактировал).

Comment: Yaant, я предполагаю, что при N = 11 M должно быть тоже равным 11. И спасибо за совет.

Comment: Yaant, я написал код по вашему алгоритму, но он не работает для всех случаев. Например, с числом 99 - ответ должен быть по идее никакой (я не смог разложить число 99 на произведение цифр). Код по вашему алгоритму я добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Кот Программов Наверное, не всё учтено из подсказки Yaant. Например, для N=81 код не даст 99. А почему?

Comment: @MBo потому что я невнимательно прочитал подсказку! нужно делить на одно число до тех пор, пока делится, а не делить на одно и сразу проверять, делится ли на другое. Но тогда возникнет другая проблема - а как же правильно получить и вывести число M (3-ий код с правильной реализацией подсказки я добавил в вопрос). На некоторых тестах проходит, а на некоторых нет. Для теста 50, к примеру, не работает - должен вывести 255, а выводит ничего.

Comment: Потому что код делает что попало. Какой диапазон проходит  цикл? Почему добавляется  `s += [y]`, а не [i]. Добавил ответ, респекты Yaant

Comment: @MBo спасибо за код, всё предельно ясно и понятно. Понимаю, что я довольно-таки криворукий.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 640
z = 0
t = 1
for i in range (9, 1, -1):
    while x % i == 0:
        z += i * t
        t *= 10
        x //= i
if x == 1:
    print(z)
else:
    print("nope")
```

Answer (score 0):

Доделал вариант MBo для случаев когда N=1..9 тогда M должно быть равно 11..19.

```
x = 1
z = 0
t = 1
for i in range (9, 1, -1):
    while x % i == 0:
        z += i * t
        t *= 10
        x //= i
if x == 1:
    if z==0:
        z=11
    else: 
        if z<10:
            z+=10
    print(z)
else:
    print("nope")
```

Comment: я сделал проще: просто добавил конструкцию if... else. типа if x < 10: print(10 + x) else: и код MBo.

Comment: Тогда у вас при N=1 M=10 что неправильно. Просто при x=1 z=0 а нужно 11

Comment: Хотя мне кажется это ошибка в условии, если N>10, а не M то алгоритм вообще не надо переделывать.